# Rust UDP connection not working but netcat does

Tags: networking, rust, udp, netcat

I'm trying to get data that is sent via udp to port 20777 on my mac. Running a listener with netcat, I'm able to receive the data: `nc -u -l 0.0.0.0 20777`.

However, the following rust code hangs on `recv_from`...

```
use std::net::UdpSocket;

use bytebuffer::ByteBuffer;

let socket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:20777").expect("Failed to bind to port!");

loop {
    let mut buf = [0; 2048];
    match socket.recv_from(&mut buf) {
        Ok((size, _addr)) => {
            println!("Got {} bytes", size); 
        }
        Err(_) => println!("Failed")
    }
}
```

What could be causing this issue...

Comment: I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work. I suspect a firewall or other security mechanism is preventing the Rust program from receiving the traffic.

Comment: The strange thing is that it randomly worked for a period, but then went back to failing... My firewall is off. When you say "other security mechanisms", what could those be?

Comment: Your code definitely [works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=35d4bdf00f8687ec77e16ba3cb1fc9b0) it might be that you don't fill the buffer and the system is waiting to do so though. `UdpSocket` might be line buffered or something.

Comment: if you launch your program too many time it's possible os didn't release the port yet.

Comment: @cafce25 I don't think it's buffered; the docs say "Receives a single datagram message on the socket" which is what I would expect for UDP. This smells more like some application-level firewall, such as whatever Mac's counterpart to the built-in Windows firewall is. (I avoid Macs in general, but I assume they have something similar.)

Comment: @Stargateur If that was the case, wouldn't the bind fail?

Comment: with udp not necessary but last time I did udp networking was long time ago in C

Comment: @Stargateur You're thinking of TIME_WAIT in TCP. UDP does not have a 'release the port' phase.